# Why google chrome doesn't show my html code?

Tags: html, css

I created a file "index.html" and opened it on google chrome but a page doesn't show anything. I think that the problem is with my browser settings because that code worked before the system update. However, I can't find a solution. Here's my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="description" content="The page presents TOP 5 TV serials. Check them out!"/>
      <meta name="keywors" content="TOP 5, serials, the best, the most interesting, watch, share">
      <title>The best serials - TOP 5!</title>

      <style>
      #container
      {
        width: 1000px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
      #logo
      {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
      }
      #nav
      {
        float: left;
        background-color: lightgray;
        width: 140px;
        min-height: 620px;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      #content
      {
        float: left;
        width: 640px;
        padding: 20px;
      }
      #ad
      {
        float: left;
        background-color: lightgray;
        width: 140px;
        min-height: 620px;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      #footer
      {
        clear: both;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
      }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="container">

        <div id="logo">
          <h1>The best serials - TOP 5!</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="nav">
          Dr House<br/>
          True Detective<br/>
          Breaking Bad<br/>
          Big Bang Theory<br/>
          The X Files<br/>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
          House (also called House, M.D.) is an American television medical drama that originally ran on the Fox network for eight seasons, from November 16, 2004 to May 21, 2012. The show's main character is Dr. Gregory House (Hugh Laurie), a pain medication-dependent, unconventional, misanthropic medical genius who leads a team of diagnosticians at the fictional Princeton–Plainsboro Teaching Hospital (PPTH) in New Jersey.

          <br/><br/>

          The show's premise originated with Paul Attanasio, while David Shore, who is credited as creator, was primarily responsible for the conception of the title character. The show's executive producers included Shore, Attanasio, Attanasio's business partner Katie Jacobs, and film director Bryan Singer. It was filmed largely in Century City.
        </div>

        <div id="ad">
          <img src="ad.jpg"/>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
          The best serials - TOP 5! &copy; All rights reserved
        </div>
      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Where's your opening `<body>` tag or the opening `<html>` tag? Please show the full HTML file in one block of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `title` tag is broken.

Instead of `<title>The best serials - TOP 5!</title="">` you should have `<title>The best serials - TOP 5!</title>`.

For more details: http://devdocs.io/html/element/title

And your doctype is also broken. Use `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` instead of `<!DOCTYPE>`.

For more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Doctype

Answer (score 0):

At the very top it has to be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
```

not

```
<!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
```